# What does d3.scale.ordinal() mean

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can somebody explain what this block of code does:

```
colorScale = (options.colors) ? d3.scale.ordinal().range(options.colors.map(
            function (d) {
               return (is.Number(d)) ? toHexColor(d) : d;
            })) : d3.scale.category20();
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking what a scale is, what an ordinal scale is, or simply what does this block of code do.

Comment: i would like to know what does this block of code do.

Comment: It either creates an ordinal scale based on given colors or it uses a predefined d3 ordinal scale (`d3.scale.category20()`).

Comment: In particular, if `options.colors` is set, it uses those colours, otherwise a default D3 color scale.